# Can I ensure that files selected by glob are in a particular order? Does 0_..., 1_... etc offer guarantees?

Tags: shell, zsh

Gathering Knowledge on the internet I found this method of sourcing files to .zshrc to be very convenient for me. But my question is how would this for loop work and which files will be loaded 1st?
For example of if I have a file called 0_alias.zsh and then 1_options.zsh. Will the file with name 0 be loaded 1st?

```
function src {
    [[ -r "$1" ]] && source "$1"
}

if [[ -d ~/.config/.zshell/func.d/ ]]; then
    for func in ~/.config/.zshell/func.d/*.zsh; do
        src "$func"
    done
    unset func
fi
```

Comment: Globbing is by locale order. So yes, as long as there are not more than 9 files, `0_` and then `1_` will be fine. If you want to work with up to 100, use `00_` then `01_`, etc; to work with up to 1000, make it `000_`, `001_`, etc.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy zsh has a way to sort as desired without having to resort to that leading 0 trick, btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zsh [glob qualifiers](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) include some options to control the sorting of the expanded filenames with the `oX` qualifier. Unfortunately, they only include things like sorting by file size or last-modified timestamp, not "version sort" where runs of digits are sorted numerically instead of lexicographically. However, [parameter expansion flags](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags) *do* include such a sort option, so you can break it up into a couple of steps:

```bash
# Array of all expanded filenames
files=( ~/.config/.zshell/func.d/*.zsh )
# Iterate over all elements of the array in "version" order
for func in ${(n)files[@]}; do
    # stuff
done
```

This way you can get files in the desired order without having to resort to things like padding the names with leading 0's to get them to sort lexicographically.

Example:

```bash
$ files=( *.zsh )

# Default lexicographic order
$ print ${files[@]}
0_foo.zsh 123_quux.zsh 1_bar.zsh 23_baz.zsh

# "Version" order
$ print ${(n)files[@]}
0_foo.zsh 1_bar.zsh 23_baz.zsh 123_quux.zsh
```

---

### But forget all that.

@Gairfowl mentioned a `numeric_glob_sort` option. Turns out that can be turned on just for a single expansion in the qualifiers - it's not with the `oX` sort options which is why I missed it earlier. So all you really need is:

```bash
for func in  ~/.config/.zshell/func.d/*.zsh(n); do
    # stuff
done
```

Comment: There's also `setopt numeric_glob_sort`, but it has global effect. (One way to make it local: `(){setopt numeric_glob_sort local_options;print -l *.zsh}`)

Comment: Thanks. Is this going to be slower than padding names? because there is an extra sort step involved?

Comment: @SyedShanto Not enough to be noticeable unless you have thousands of files, and probably not even then.

Comment: @Gairfowl Turns out that you can turn that option on for a single glob pattern with the `(n)` qualifier. Wish I'd seen that first when I was checking the documentation.

Comment: @Shawn - same :).  Had memories of using that sort before, and then thought I was mistaken when I didn't find it with the other sort options.

Comment: Thanks guys. I like the syntax for numeric glob.